# No parameterless constructor exception when attempting to read past the end of stream

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I've been struggling with the exception `'No parameterless constructor found for [type]'` for the past few hours. Now I created a simple unit test which should mirror what I've got in the application and it seems that this exception is thrown when I don't do `stream.Position = 0`.

Also, I don't get this exception in any case when the object is just a standard class (not derived from an abstract one).

See the code below:

1. run it as is - it will break saying that no constructor could be found for Base
2. uncomment stream.Position = 0 and it will be fine
3. comment the line out again, change the Derived class to not inherit from Base and uncomment the only property in the class, run it - it won't break (but obviously the Name will be null)

Can someone explain why this works this way ? Why #1 throws (or why #3 doesn't) and why this message?

```
[Test]
public void CanSerialize_Derived()
{
    var derived = new Derived() {Name = "ngf"};
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, derived);
    //stream.Position = 0;
    var deserializedInstance = Serializer.Deserialize<Derived>(stream);
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(9, typeof(Derived))]
public abstract class Base 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Derived : Base
{
    //[ProtoMember(1)]
    //public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A stream of length zero is valid in protobuf-net; in protobuf-net all serialization starts at the root type of that DTO inheritance tree, so it would *start* at `Base` - and until it can **agree** that the data actually contains a `Derived`, it won't believe you - and will try to work with `Base`. So that is why #1 throws.

Obviously, if you leave the stream at the end, the length of data available to be deserialized is zero. Which is why #2 passes.

If you remove the inheritance, then the root of that inheritance tree is `Derived`; that is a fundamentally breaking change, but the difference in terms of inheritance is that it is no longer trying to deserialize an `abstract` type without any information. So that is why #3 fixes it (for bad reasons).

The key takeaway here is that inheritance is *implemented as information*. The only thing it assumes, unless there is information, is that the object is of the type at the root of the inheritance tree.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - the behaviour makes more sense now indeed.